# Removing a static selection area (string) in a file for multiple lines into a new file

Tags: windows, performance, sed, command-line

I have a huge text file of over 121 million lines in it.  I need to remove, for each line, a static selection area of 29 characters. The static selection area does not start at the beginning of the line, but as per the example below, rather from the end of the date value on the line.  Notepad++ grinds to a halt when trying to use it, so looking for something like SED or similar which can also run under Windows. Speed of the util would be a bonus as it is very slow in a GUI editor.

Example:

### File contents:

```
2020/05/06  12:59 PM                413 S_EMT_001.SAF
2020/05/06  10:21 PM                413 S_EMT_002.SAF
```

### Desired result:

```
2020/05/06 S_EMT_001.SAF
2020/05/06 S_EMT_002.SAF
```

Comment: you say 29 characters but your examples remove 13 characters

Comment: you can use sed in WSL

Comment: Note that WSL-2 suffer from very slow IO operations (it may still be enough for your needs though). AFAIK, sed on Windows does not behave always like the one on Linux so this solve at least this cumbersome issue. Note you can use Python for that or any scripting language (Perl should be good for text operations too). Such solution is portable and certainly fast enough. A line-per-line search and replace is rather trivial in Python. Regexp parsing should be even simpler and more flexible but significantly slower (whatever the target language).

Comment: An simple example in Python: `s = open('in_file').read(1_000_000_000)`, then compute the replacement: `out = '\n'.join(e[0]+' '+e[2] for e in re.findall(r'([0-9/]+) (.* )?([a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+)', s))`, and finally store the result: `open('out_file', 'w').write(out)`. It takes about 2 seconds on my machine on a 120 MiB file (due to the slow regexp). Note `re` needs to be imported first. One can certainly use this pattern to make a sed alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
cut -c 1-10,24-
```

Which is:

- Keep characters 1-10
- Keep characters 24 and later
- Effectively discard characters 11-23

Answer (score 0):

With a POSIX sed:

```
sed 's/^\(.\{10\}\).\{29\}/\1/' file
```

With GNU sed (or BSD sed) we can simplify a bit:

```
sed -E 's/^(.{10}).{29}/\1/' file
```